# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, shopping-cart

I'm using the version of that gem https://github.com/crowdint/acts_as_shopping_cart for rails 3

I did everything with the conventions names. But I'm getting the error Can't mass-assign protected attributes: item

```
class ShoppingCartsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :extract_shopping_cart
  def create
    @product = Video.find(params[:product_id])
    @shopping_cart.add(@product, @product.price) # the error is generated on that line
    redirect_to shopping_cart_path
  end
```

My model ShoppingCart:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: shopping_carts
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class ShoppingCart < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_shopping_cart

    attr_accessible :price

    #accepts_nested_attributes_for :price
end
```

My model ShoppingCartItem:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: shopping_cart_items
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  owner_id   :integer
#  owner_type :string(255)
#  quantity   :integer
#  item_id    :integer
#  item_type  :string(255)
#  price      :float
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class ShoppingCartItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :owner_id, :owner_type, :quantity, :item_id, :item_type, :price
  acts_as_shopping_cart_item
end
```

Can anyone help me what I am missing here?

Comment: Did you try adding :item to attr_accessible ?

Comment: Yes, and accepts_nested_attributes_for

Comment: Put it in both model and see where it belongs

Answer (score 0):

hope u are aware that

**Rails 3**

*As of Version 0.2.0 Rails 3 is no longer supported. Please use the 0-1-x branch if you still need to implement this gem in a Rails 3 app*

```
gem 'acts_as_shopping_cart', :github => 'crowdint/acts_as_shopping_cart', :branch => '0-1-x'
```

Comment: Yes I saw that and I'm using this version. Thanks!